# Convergence of a sequence of integrable random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Suppose that $X_1,X_2, \dots$ is a sequence of integrable random variables, which decreases to a random variable $X$. I am trying to prove that if $$\inf_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}(X_n) > -\infty$$ then $X \in L^1$ and $X_n$ converges to $X$ in $L^1$.

But I couldn't proceed into any way, can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: Apply Monotone convergence theorem to $\{-X_n\}$.